# Error when accessing Google Storage Account through Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, databricks

I'm using community.cloud.databricks.com/ to access Storage Account Google and it gives me error:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable","true")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.email",
  "xxxx@kkkk.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.project.id", "oval-replica-9999999")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key","xxx")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key.id","yyyy")


df = spark.read.format("csv").load("gs://accounttest081212/")
```

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server at: 
http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like an authentication exception. Can your application access the internet?